# Why are my wordpress shortcodes not working when using the plugin boilerplate?

Tags: php, wordpress

I would like to add my shortcodes from a separate file within my plugin, generated by the WP Plugin Boilerplate. I have the following codes:

in class-PLUGIN_NAME.php:

```
public function __construct() {
        if ( defined( 'PLUGIN_NAME_VERSION' ) ) {
            $this->version = PLUGIN_NAME_VERSION;
        } else {
            $this->version = '1.0.0';
        }
        $this->plugin_name = 'PLUGIN_NAME';

        $this->load_dependencies();
        $this->set_locale();
        $this->define_admin_hooks();
        $this->define_public_hooks();
        $this->define_shortcodes();

    }

private function define_shortcodes(){

    $shortcodes_class = new PLUGIN_NAME_Shortcodes( $this->get_plugin_name(), $this->get_version() );

    $this->loader->add_shortcode( 'event-create', $shortcodes_class, 'event_create' );

}
```

in class-PLUGIN-NAME-loader.php

```
protected $shortcodes;

public function add_shortcode( $tag, $component, $callback) {
    $this->shortcodes = $this->add( $this->shortcodes, $tag, $component, $callback );
}

public function run() {
    foreach ( $this->shortcodes as $hook ) {
        add_shortcode( $hook['hook'], array( $hook['component'], $hook['callback'] ) );
    }
}
```

And in class-PLUGIN_NAME-Shortcodes.php:

```
public static function event_create(){
    echo "Hello, world!";
}
```

Then when I view a page that contains the tag [event-create], I get an error saying `do_shortcode_tag was called incorrectly. Attempting to parse a shortcode without a valid callback: event-create`

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: I don't know the plugin boilerplate, but try to replace` 'event_create'` by `array($this, 'event_create')`. And don't do an `echo` directly, instead of `echo` use `return`.

Comment: That's what the add_shortcode function in the foreach loop in the run method does. And changing echo to return didn't fix it either.

Answer (score 0):

In your cass-PLUGIN-NAME.php you can put the shortcode under the private function defince_public_hooks()

```
private function define_public_hooks() {

    //add shortcode
    $this->loader->add_shortcode( 'name_of_shortcode', $plugin_public, 'function_name_to_call' );
    
}
```

In your class-PLUGIN-NAME-loader.php

```
public function run() {

    foreach ( $this->shortcodes as $hook ) {
        add_shortcode( $hook['hook'], array( $hook['component'], $hook['callback'] ) );
    }

public function add_shortcode( $tag, $component, $callback, $priority = 10, $accepted_args = 2 ) {
    $this->shortcodes = $this->add( $this->shortcodes, $tag, $component, $callback, $priority, $accepted_args );
}
```

In your class-PLUGIN_NAME-public.php

```
public function function_name_to_call($atts) {
    ob_start();
    require_once plugin_dir_path( dirname( __FILE__ ) ) . 'public/partials/TEMPLATE_FILE_NAME.php';
    return ob_get_clean();
}
```

OR

```
public function function_name_to_call($atts) {
    echo( 'Hello World' );
}
```